# Python 3 Why here append() can take two arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am fresh to Python 3. As I am learning tuple, I find this code in book.

```
txt = 'but sort what light in yonder window breaks'
words = txt.split()
t = list()
for word in words:
    t.append((len(word),word))

t.sort(reverse = True)

res = list()

for length, word in t:
    res.append(word)

print(res)
```

I have two questions for this code. first the book says:

> The first loop builds a list of tuples, where each tuple is a word preceded by its length.

How did the first loop create a list of tuples? From tutorial, I learned tuple are created like below.

```
t = ('a',)
t = 'a', 'b', 'c'
t = tuple()
```

Second question is why here append() can take two arguments?

```
t.append((len(word),word))
```

Comment: The tuples are of the form `(len(word),  word)` and `t` is a list of them. For example: `(5, "hello")`, `append()` takes one argument here, that is the tuple: `(len(word),  word)`

Comment: @Nic. Thanks a lot. I understand it now

Answer (score 0):

`append` didn't get two arguments , it get one `tuple` , as you saw in tutorial tuple are `(var_1, var_2)` like , so in this example `len(word)` and `word` are two tuple variables , so `t` is a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks very much. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

`append()` here only takes 1 argument if you look carefully. That argument happens to be a tuple of 2 elements.